# SUM the result of dividing two cells (SUMPRODUCT but division instead)

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

I'm looking to do the equivalent of `SUMPRODUCT` but with division. Is there a way to add the results from dividing two arrays?

Example: Column A has the "life" of an asset in years `(10, 20, 10)`. Column B has the Value of the asset `(10,000, 20,000, 20,000)`. I want to add the result of `(10,000/10) + (20,000/20) + (20,000/10) = 4,000`, but for the formula to be dynamic as I add rows with life and value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since the division is the inverse of the multiplication, you can use this:

=SUMPRODUCT(1/A1:A3, B1:B3)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that this worked without using array formulas (i.e., ctrl+shift+enter). But why does it work for SUMPRODUCT and not for e.g., SUM(1/A1:A3)?

Answer (score 9):

You can do that with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10/A2:A10)`

no blanks or zeroes allowed in the column A range...

edit: missed dynamic part....either use dynamic named ranges....or you can use this array version to allow up to 1000 rows, where later ones are blank

`=SUM(IF(A2:A1000<>0,B2:B1000/A2:A1000))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Answer (score -2):

Actually the best formula is this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(E2:E10))/(SUM(D2:10))
```

You can also combine the formula with another one like the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(E2:10))/(count(D2:D10))
```

Good luck