# Why can we use division operator in Excel's SUMPRODUCT(), but not in other functions?

Tags: arrays, excel

I was surprised to find that in Excel you can divide a range in the SUMPRODUCT function (per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650170/50899). Note that this doesn't require the  use of array formulas (i.e, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> is not necesary)

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(1/A1:A3, B1:B3)           <= note the division operator
```

But why can you NOT do it for, e.g., `=SUM(1/A1:A3)`?
To which functions can it be applied? 
And what is the name of this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT does array calculations under the covers, but SUM does not. 
Array entering {SUM(A1:A3/10)} gives the same answer as SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3/10) but SUMPRODUCT does not need array entering because Excel already knows that its an array processing function.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to know which other functions (like sumproduct) do array calculations under the cover?

Comment: Even SUM can work without CSE if you have the numbers specified as an "array constant", e.g. =SUM(1/{3,4,5})....but in general I think only SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP functions have this capability - although using IF functions normally forces you to use CSE (even within SUMPRODUCT) as does use of TRANSPOSE function